# PyCharm venv issue "pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available"

Tags: python, pip, pycharm

I would like to use PyCharm to develop in Python. I have looked around but do not seem to be able to find any solutions to my issue.

I have Python 3 installed using the Windows msi. I am using Windows 10. have downloaded PyCharm version 2019.3.1 (Community Edition). I create a new project using the Pure Python option.

On trying to pip install any package, I get the error:

> pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available

If I try this in VSCode using the terminal it works fine.

How can I resolve this issue? It would appear to be a problem with the virtual environment but I do not know enough to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry guys, it appears the basic interpreter option was on Anaconda, that I had installed sometime ago , forgotten about and it defaulted to it . Changing my basic interpreter option to my Python install (Python.exe) solved the issue.

Keep on learning

Comment: Known issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-35053, please vote